# KendoUI Restrict the Dimensions of the SVG and Paths

Tags: javascript, svg, scale, kendo-ui

I am having trouble constraining the dimensions of a KendoUI line graph to the parent div.  For some graphs it works fine, but for charts with more data values along the x-axis, the svg is fed pixel dimensions greater than the dimensions of its parent.  The same is true for the path dimensions.  This creates overflow in both x and y.  Is there a way to force the svg and various paths to scale to the dimensions of the parent div?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. It seems whenever there's too many iterations of data in kendo the size acts really funny. I hope there's a fix for this, because kendo seems like a really nice chart framework and I'd like to be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width on the chart div itself.  I constrained one here.  It looks terrible, but just to show that you can squeeze it down..

http://jsfiddle.net/burkeholland/drXnR/